# Bootstrap Well Padding Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a problem when I try to wrap a well around several grid elements. I'm not sure if it works like this out of the box or if I'm not sure where to place the well class.

http://jsfiddle.net/AdamFollett/9xS8Y/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3">
                        55 Fake Street<br />
                        St. Johns<br/>
                        A1E3A2<br/>
                    </div>        
                    <div class="span3">
                        more Info<br />
                        Blah Blah<br/>
                        Blah<br/>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Use Location" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <img alt="googlemap" class="googlemap" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.221805,-79.858946&zoom=14&size=320x240&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|43.221805,-79.858946&sensor=false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The two span3 elements will not space correctly when the well class is included. Am I not using the class correctly or will I need to add my own CSS to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish? You can add the `well` directly to the `span` if you want... [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xS8Y/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the `DIV` with the `well` class I think because it takes the full length of the row, and then you have 2 `span3` `DIV` inside taking more space than the `well`  they are inside (not sure if I'm clear enough)

However, if you replace your inner `row` class with `row-fluid` and set the two inner `DIV`'s classes to `span6`, it should display as you want:

```
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">55 Fake Street
                    <br />Fake Town
                    <br/>A1B2C3
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">more Info
                    <br />Blah Blah
                    <br/>Blah
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Use Location" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've forked your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3KDjP/1/).

Comment: This is perfect Thanks! You can even just remove the well div and put the well class right on the top level span6.